# mongodb mapReduce for sailsjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to sort two Collections based on creation time. I searched through stackoverflow and found the solution which was mentioned this link http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/ that is you mapReduce the collections to another Collection named joined and later sort using a given parameter(creation time in my case).

The problem now is how we mapReduce in Sailsjs, I have already referred this http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native where we have this code.

```
Pet.native(function(err, collection) {
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);

  collection.find({}, {
    name: true
  }).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    return res.ok(results);
  });
});
```

the collection parameter in the callback carries properties such as find, create and so on. Does collection parameter have the function **mapReduce** ? Since it was undefined in my case.

Is there any way to mapReduce in Sailsjs apart from opening a raw connection and using the connection opened in config/connection.js(default connection).

Or better any way to sort 2 Collections in mongodb based on a particular attribute?

Sails v0.11.5, node v0.4.4.2

Thanks.

Comment: Because `native()` returns a raw Mongo collection instance representing the specified model, you should be able to implement the [**`.mapReduce()`**](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.1/lib/collection.js#L3017) method on the collection as it's part of the [node-mongodb-native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#introduction).

Comment: I understand the .mapReduce() method is functionality of node-mongodb-native (that can be used by installing npm install mongodb), and you have connect to the mongodb using new connection and use .mapReduce(). I actually don't want to open a new connection and solve the issue using the given sailsjs mongodb connection which is configured in config/connections.js. Thanks.